# named mmap without Disk IO

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, mmap

I wanted to use the POSIX standard mmap as if shmat had an id, they share the same shared memory.
mmap seems to normally use fd=-1 when using MAP_ANON, and in this case it is said to be valid when inheriting from a child process.

I wanted to ensure the same behavior in the spawn method. Then I can use named shared memory, but I wish it didn't do DISK IO at all. 
I think MAP_ANON is essential because I want to always guarantee the speed of RAM without leaving any files on the DISK in case of an unexpected shutdown.

So is it reasonable to provide fd!=-1 while being MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct stat sb;
    char *p;
    int fd;
    
    fd = shm_open("test",  O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);
    
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    
    size_t len = 128;
    if (ftruncate(fd, len) == -1) {
        perror("ftruncate");
        return 1;
    }
    
    p = (char*)mmap(0, len, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED){
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    
    }
    
    if (close(fd)==-1) {
        perror("close");
        return 1;
    
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        putchar(p[i]);
    }
    
    if (munmap(p, len) == -1) {
        perror("munmap");
        return 1;
    }

    if(shm_unlink("test")) {
        perror("unlink");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `shm_open` already creates file in `tmpfs` on Linux, so it is backed by memory. This is the best you can do with POSIX. Linux also has `memfd_create` which can help, although I am not sure what you need.

Comment: @StaceyGirl With your answer, I found that MAP_ANON eventually works on main memory regardless (thanks!). Is there a working difference with or without the MAP_ANON flag in the code above?

Comment: `MAP_ANON` makes `mmap` ignore `fd` argument. So if you want to use `shm_open`, it should be removed, otherwise `shm_open` idoes nothing useful here. if you are forking, then you just seeing shared anonymous memory. The problem is with transferring it throught `exec` syscall.

Comment: To create named shared memory with mmap without doing disk IO, use /tmp